# jQuery keyup() illegal characters

Tags: jquery, key

I have a field and want to prevent some illegal characters while showing the user as he types.
How can I do this in follow example?

```
  $('input').bind("change keyup", function() {
   var val = $(this).attr("value");
   /*
   if (val --contains-- '"') {
    $(this).css("background", "red");
           val = val.replace('"', "");
              $(this).attr("value", val)
   }
   */
   $("p").html(val);
  });
```

EDIT: I should put the illegal characters in an array

```
var vowels = new Array('"', "<", ">", "&");
```

Comment: Why do you want them in an array?

Comment: eeuuh, because there are a few of them? dunno.. Maybe it can be done with regular expressions, but that's Chinese to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use a regular expression.

```
$('input').bind("change keyup", function() {
 var val = $(this).val();
 var regex = /["<>&]/g;
 if (val.match(regex)) {
   $(this).css("background", "red");
   val = val.replace(regex, "");
   $(this).val(val);
 }
 $("p").html(val);
});
```

And FYI: you can replace `.attr("value",val)` with `.val(val)` and `.attr("value")` with `.val()`

**UPDATE:**

If you want to exclude more characters you can just put them into the regex. If you want to exclude an character that is used to control the regex you need to escape them with `\` characters to control the regex are: `[]()/\+{}?*+.^$`

Comment: Great! Thanks for the .val() tip also Jens. Cheers

Comment: You should probably utilize `g` (global identifier) in case a user uses the GUI to copy and paste text with multiple excluded characters.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try. No array, though.

```
    $('input').bind("change keyup", function() {
        var $th = $(this);
        $th.val( $th.val().replace(/["<>&]/g, function(str) {  return ''; } ) );
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the indexOf to determine if a string contains a certain char...

vowels = array('"', "<", ">", "&");

```
$('input').bind("change keyup", function()
{
   var val = $(this).attr("value");
   var illegal = '';       
   $(vowels).each(function()
   {
      if(val.indexOf(this)!=-1)
      {
          illegal= this;
          break;
      }
   });
   if(illegal != '') 
   {
       $(this).css("background", "red");
       val = val.replace(illegal, "");
       $(this).attr("value", val)
   }
});
```