# TEXTBOX with Restriction in Symbols,Characters and Numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am facing difficulties in Restricting **Textbox** Values.

The Textbox should not allow Symbols other than **`"?*,"`**.

Ex: `A123?*,B456?*,C789?*,D126?*,E?*666`

After and before comma `(,)` only **`10 Characters/Symbols/Numbers`** are allowed.

only **`54 characters`** are allowed inside Textbox including comma's.

Only **`4 comma's`** are allowed inside TEXTBOX.

Possible Text-box Inputs:  **`ABC?12345*,A?BC*12345,A???1234**,?*C?12345*,ABC?123***`**

Also the Symbols and character are replaceable, Either at the start - Symbol might come or character or Numbers.

Kindly check the image for more clarification.
[image]

I tried restricting with other Symbols and Allowed commas but I am facing difficulties in Restricting with 10 characters and allowing symbols and number of characters.

```
//<![CDATA[ 
window.onload = function() {
    /*var f = document.getElementById('textbox_restrict');
     f.addEventListener('keyup', function(evt){
     alert("Vinayagam");
     var regex = /[^a-zA-Z0-9]/;
     if(regex.test(this.value)) {
     this.value = this.value.replace(regex, '')  
     }
     });*/
    $('#textbox_restrict').keypress(function(e) {
        $('#backgroundPopup').animate({'opacity': 0.0, 'display': 'none'});
        this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9a-zA-Z\*\?\{0,12}]/g, '').toUpperCase();
    });

}//]]>  

$(function() {
    $('body').on('keyup', 'input[id^="textbox_restrict"]', function() {
        this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9a-zA-Z\*\?]/g, '').toUpperCase();
    });

    $('#search').live('click', function() {
    }); // End of save click function
}); // End of function
```

[I also took reference to this Question but the senario is different:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050749/how-restrict-textbox-in-c-sharp-to-only-receive-numbers-and-dot-or-comma)
[How restrict textbox in C# to only receive numbers and (dot "." or comma ","), after "." or "," only allow 2 number characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050749/how-restrict-textbox-in-c-sharp-to-only-receive-numbers-and-dot-or-comma)

[Regex Replace anything but numbers and lowercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147433/regex-replace-anything-but-numbers-and-lowercase?rq=1)

[jQuery keyup() illegal characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866108/jquery-keyup-illegal-characters?lq=1)

Kindly Advice me! I was a bit confused to implement it.

Comment: Do you need something like this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U5zq3/1/)?

Comment: @Teemu it will be much helpfull to understand the working code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Eh... I didn't quite understand your comment, do you want me to post the snippet as an answer? Though you've accepted an answer already.

Comment: I might be accepted the answer from Paul but sure if you answer help me to understand it better I will accept your answer as well. because I searched thought out internet for this answer but I found here so some one might need your working answer for there problem.@Teemu...

Comment: That is why I explained my question clearly and with a snap shoot.... things will be easy for others to understand. your jsfiddle will add a advantage for others to understand.

Comment: I am facing one more issue in the solution.. when ever I edit any numbers/characters inside the text box the arrow points to the end of the TEXTBOX. but is should stay on where I edited? How can we solve it

Comment: Please be mindful when tagging questions. The [tag:jquery-validate] tag is for a specific plugin, which is not part of your question.  Edited. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry @Sparky I thought it wrong.. Thanks for your edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's better not to try to get all stuff done at once. I've cutted the task into pieces to simplify each stage. Just add the snippet below as a `keyup` or rather an `oninput` eventhandler to your `input`.

```
keyUp = function () {
    var n, parts, temp,
        text = this.value,
        caretPos = this.selectionEnd; // Stores the caret position
    parts = text.split(','); // Creates an array of comma separated values
    while (parts.length > 5) { // Limits the array length to 5 i.e only 4 commas allowed
        parts.pop();
    }
    for (n = 0; n < parts.length; n++) { // Iterates through each comma separated string
        parts[n] = parts[n].substring(0, 10); // Limits the string length to 10
        temp = parts[n].match(/[0-9a-zA-Z\*\?]/g); // Creates an array of acceptable characters in the string
        if (temp) {
            parts[n] = temp.join(''); // Adds the accepted value to the original
        } else { // If not value, add empty to the original
            parts[n] = '';
        }
    }
    this.value = parts.join(',').toUpperCase(); // Creates a new acceptable value to the input
    this.setSelectionRange(caretPos, caretPos); // Returns the caret to the original position
    return;
}
```

A live demo at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U5zq3/4/).

**EDIT**

Removed string supress to 54 to avoid accidentally removed characters at the end of the string when adding characters in the middle of the string. Added `else` which will add an empty string in a case acceptable value wasn't found. Also looks like `oninput` would be a better event with this code.

**EDIT II**

Added a caret position returning to the original position after edited the string in the middle of it. Not perfect when pasting text with mouse, but seems to work on keyboard enter. (The fiddle link is updated.)

Comment: Its great! working like charm. because of the functions and the logic I accepted your answer. as it is nice to receive an answer with working example. I will upvote it once my votecast is avail. thanks for you code.

Comment: I also like accept Paul's answer but stackover flow was restricted? :( its complicated for me to use REGEXP as I will use dynamic Textboxes.

Comment: I am facing a small issue in the code.. My LEFT ARROW is not working.. I am not able to move to left. If I use KEYPRESS its working but the last character in the TEXTBOX is not converted to upper case. :(

Comment: Hmm, I can't reproduce that issue (Firefox). Anyway, there seems to be some other issues too, please check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U5zq3/2/), it fixes some problems, maybe the left arrow too.

Comment: I am facing one more issue in the solution.. when ever I edit any numbers/characters inside the text box the arrow points to the end of the TEXTBOX. but is should stay on where I edited? How can we solve it.

Comment: Well, I was waiting for this... That's a curse of realtime validation. It can be solved with some `Selection` and `Range` objects, though a cross-browser code would be multiple times bigger than this original snippet. In FF the caret stays at a correct position by pressing SHIFT simultaneously with another key, though this is not a solution. Questions about this subject can be found at SO, I think some of those might even have good answers... If you can't find anything suitable, you can ask a question about this.

Comment: @TomPHP I've managed to develope something simple. It seems to work at least in FF, Chrome and IE10. HTML5 provides suprises every day : ).

Comment: Can we implement this in JQuery because this functionality is not working in Dynamic fields or in other works in same page multiple textboxes..?? I am facing difficulties after difficulties..

Comment: Actually there's no jQuery implementation for anything in the code (?), except you can attach the handler with jQuery ofcourse. The code is very general, it's supposed to work with multiple elements too. I'll create a multi-element fiddle (version /5/).

Comment: Sorry the code is working perfectly but the input elements are created in onload... but in my case all those are created dynamically after loading the page.. the action was triggered to create the textbox then the textbox should have the validation? there i am facing issue. in your fiddle example i see the textbox created when pageload.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32027/discussion-between-teemu-and-tomphp)

Answer (score 1):

How about this *RegExp*,

```
/^(?:[a-z\d?*]{1,10}(?:,|$)){1,5}$/i
```

From the start of the string, permit characters `a-z`, a digit, `?` and `*`, have between `1` and `10` of these, then either a comma or the end of the string. Repeat this at least once and at most `5` times. The string must then end. The `i` flag makes `a-z` include `A-Z`.

```
'A123?*,B456?*,C789?*,D126?*,E?*666'.match(/^(?:[a-z\d?*]{1,10}(?:,|$)){1,5}$/i);
// ["A123?*,B456?*,C789?*,D126?*,E?*666"]
```

It should be noted that this won't prevent a `*?`, `?x*` or `*x?` and will also not prevent a comma at the end of the string.

Comment: As you stated "It should be noted that this won't prevent a *?, ?x* or *x?." so do I want to add another function to check the symbols?

Comment: Also the Symbols and character are replaceable, Either at the start -Symbol might come or character or Numbers.

Comment: As I have it currently it doesn't care about character order, hence my note. The difficulty arises from your `10 Characters/Symbols/Numbers are allowed` with the fact that `?*` is two characters.

Comment: Yes for example : ABC?12345*,A?BC*12345,A???1234**,?*C?12345*,ABC?123*** this is a possible TextBox value.

Comment: Oh, in your OP you always put `?*` together, so I thought they must be grouped together, but if the example in your comment is valid then that is matched already so nothing more needs to be changed.

Comment: If you want to prevent commas at the end of the string, change `(?:,|$)` to `(?:,(?!$)|$)`. This uses a lookahead to make sure that if there is a comma, the next thing is not `$` (i.e. end of line)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31963/discussion-between-tomphp-and-paul-s)